# Suggest corner cases to test online assessment platform for slot booking

Tags: manual-testing, quality-assessment

What can be the scenarios/test cases for an online assessment platform where we can choose test slots according to our convenience.I have done the testing of the UI but what can be corner cases which can be fatal.

Comment: Suggestion - If you have satisfied and got resolved query with the help og any answer posted below, then accept it. So this question wont be in active thread continuously

Answer (score 2):

You can also test below cases. In our QA services company we create test cases in below manner:

1. If the application used in countries observing Daylight saving, validate the slot booking time when daylight saving starts or ends.
2. Check the number of users simultaneously take test. (as per requirements)
3. Check if user can jump between questions
4. Check if user can revisit any unanswered question
5. Check the application on mobile browsers, most software testing companies want their application to be tested on mobile browsers.
6. Try to login with same user on different machines at same time
7. Check if user can complete the test before allotted time, user should be allowed to do that
8. Appropritae validtion e.g "Are you sure you want to finish the test" should be shown before finishing the test.It saves the user when he accidently clicked on Finish Test button.
9. For open ended question: Try to put HTML codes, XSS scripts in text box. This should be handled properly by application

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Going forward, **it will be helpful if you can add what all you have done/tried?**

**Online assessment application -**

- Check time is working correctly in absence of internet, pause or resume test [if available]
- Only future Dates and Timings should be displayed to user while booking slots
- In that too, Check if there is any end date or particular time duration and expected to book slots in those dates only
- After that time user should not be allowed to book or take assessment
- User mistakenly close browser/system shut-down and tried again to continue with assessment, must be taken to proper state
- Above scenario on same machine and different browser or different machine?
- If system time manipulated by user, should not reflect anything with actual timer of assessment
- In any case, user should be thrown out after time completed

@gunschu - Above are few major test scenarios. #TryIt